# prototype behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, function-prototypes, prototype-oriented

I am confused with the following prototype behavior in javascript.

```
function A(){
};

A.prototype.toString = function(){
            console.log('first');
               }

var a = new A(), b;

A.prototype = {
    toString:function(){
        console.log('second');
    }
}

b = new A();

a.toString();
//outputs :  first

b.toString();
//outputs :  second
```

Why does **a.toString** still prints "frist" when compared to **b.toString** which prints "second".
can anyone please explain what i am missing here.

Comment: Why `var a = new A(), b`?

Comment: @basilikum: Oh I misinterpreted, he's just declaring `b` as var. It's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype link has nothing to do with the constructor that constructed
the object, it is stored on objects themselves.

When you call `new A()` this happens:

```
var a = {};
a.__proto__ = A.prototype;
A.call(a);
```

Note that the above is not standard syntax but does work in chrome and firefox.

So when you overwrite `A.prototype`, `a.__proto__` is still linking to the old `A.prototype` as you would expect with similar
code:

```
var A = 10, a, b;

a = A;
A = 7; //a is still 10
b = A;
```

I don't recommend reassigning the prototype, because then you need to re-establish the constructor property and it requires additional level of indentation.

If you want to type less, just store reference to the prototype:

```
function A() {

}
var fn = A.prototype;

fn.toString = function() {

};

fn.valueOf = function() {

};

fn.toJSON = function() {

};
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "nothing", rather an object's `[[Prototype]]` is set to the constructor's prototype *at the time the object was constructed*.

Comment: @RobG that's just basically saying the same thing :P. I am just trying to dispel the belief that the constructor is out there watching all the created instances or something.

Comment: Yes, same thing but different. :-)

Answer (score 0):

function A(){
    };

```
A.prototype.toString = function(){
            console.log('first');
               }     // here A prints 'first'

var a = new A(), b;  

A.prototype = {    
    toString:function(){
        console.log('second');
    }
}                    // here A prints 'second'

b = new A();

a.toString();
//outputs :  first

b.toString();
//outputs :  second
```

Answer (score 0):

An object's internal `[[Prototype]]` (the one it inherits from) is set to its constructor's prototype *at the time it is constructed*. Assigning a new object to the constructor's prototype does not alter the `[[Prototype]]` of instances that have already been created.

In fact, once an object is created, you can't assign a different `[[Prototype]]` other than by the non–standard [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

#### Edit

Just to make it really clear:

```
// A simple constructor
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// Assign a method to its default prototype
Person.prototype.showName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

// This instance will be assigned the above as its [[Prototype]]
// with its showName method
var fred = new Person('Fred');

// Assign a new object to Person.prototype 
Person.prototype = {};

// Assign a new showName method
Person.prototype.showName = function() {
  return 'My name is ' + this.name;
}

// This instance has the new object as its [[Prototype]]
var sue = new Person('Sue');

console.log(
    fred.showName() + '\n'  // Fred 
  + sue.showName()          // My name is Sue
);
```

It can be seen that *fred* still inherits from the original prototype object, *sue* inherits from the new object because it was created (instantiated) after the change.

Comment: How come this works

`obj = {foo:{a:1}, b:1};
function Class(){};
Class.prototype = obj;
y = new Class();
y.foo.a = 2; // prints 2
x = new Class();
x.foo.a // prints 2`

Comment: Because both *x* and *y* are created as instances of *Class* when it has the same object (*obj*) as its prototype, so *x* and *y*  have the same `[[Prototype]]` (i.e. *obj*). If you change `Class.prototype` before creating *x*, it will inherit from the new object and will have a different `[[Prototype]]` to *y*